# How to force Async completion each time in for loop, AND modify a global var?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

I am using AngularJS and I have a for loop that will call an Async function each time. Then I want to take the result of that Async and change a global function. Something like this:

```
var tweet_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var tweets_array = [];

populate_tweets = function(){
   for(var t=0; t<tweet_ids.length; t++){
      $http.get('http://localhost:8100/tweet')
          .then(function(data){
             // This will be logged after because the async takes time
             console.log(data);
             // but tweets_array does not actually get affect.. why?
             tweets_array.push(data);
          }, function(err){
             console.log(err)
          });
   }
   // This will be logged first because the Async calls are not completed yet
   console.log(tweets_array );          
}
```

The above code will not push to tweets_array, nor wait for all the Asyncs in the for loop to finish before console.log(tweets_array).

How can I get all the Asyncs in the for loop to finish, push to the tweets_array, AND THEN finally console.log(tweets_array)?

Comment: Are you using `tweet_ids[t]` anywhere?

Comment: Um, *don't* modify global variables.

Comment: So, is this client side or server side? Your tags seems to contradict each other.

Comment: @Bergi When I mean global vars I actually mean a var with a scope outside the for loop. I just didnt know how else to simply call it.

Comment: @Bergi this is client side but I would like to be able to do it on server too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use `$q.all()` to tell you when all the operations are done.  And, you can just return the data from each promise and this will keep the results in order in the final resulting array.  This will give you the follow capabilities:

1. `$q.all()` will trigger when all the requests are done.
2. All the results will be gathered in order in the final results array and will be available inside your final `.then()` handler.
3. Errors will propagate back to your one central error handler
4. No globals need to be used.
5. `get_tweets()` is made into a function that can be used more generally as it now returns a promise that fulfills with the results and error handling is exposed to the caller.  The actual of inserting them into the UI somewhere (or whatever you're doing with them can be separated out into the caller so you have more of an ability to reuse this code.

Code:

```
function get_tweets(tweet_ids) {
  var promises = [];
  for (var t = 0; t < tweet_ids.length; t++) {
      promises.push($http.get('http://localhost:8100/tweet').then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;  // let this be the resolved value of the promise
      }));
  }
  return $q.all(promises);
}

get_tweets([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]).then(function(results) {    
      // results is an array of all the results, in order
}, function(err) {
      // process error here
});
```

FYI, I assume the real code needs to include the proper `tweet_id` somewhere in the request URL.

**Also, a few general words of advice in this topic area:**

1. **Never use global variables to collect the results** from an asynchronous operation.  Because asynchronous operations are done at some unknown, indeterminate future time, there is no way to reliably use the global variables outside of the completion handler for the asynchronous operation.  So, since the results of the async operation are known in the completion handler, just use them there and avoid ever using the global scope for them.  I have never seen a desirable design pattern that collected async results in a global variable.
2. When you have more than one async operation that you need to coordinate, **promises are an idea tool for letting you know when multiple async operations are complete**.
3. **Do not forget about proper error handling with async operations.**  While error handling can be more complex in hand-written async code, learning how to propagate errors back with promises is very simple once you learn how to use the natural propagation of a rejected promise and the `reason` for the rejection.  Use this natural capability of promises.
4. **Try to separate out the fetching of data from the processing of that data** into separate functions (like inserting it into the UI).  This will generally make writing, testing and reusing portions of the code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` method from `$q` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

**all(promises):**
Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.'

```js
var tweet_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var tweets_array = [];
var tweetFetchPromises = [];

populate_tweets = function() {
  for (var t = 0; t < tweet_ids.length; t++) {
    var promise = $http.get('http://localhost:8100/tweet')
      .then(function(data) {
        // This will be logged after because the async takes time
        console.log(data);
        // but tweets_array does not actually get affect.. why?
        tweets_array.push(data);
      }, function(err) {
        console.log(err)
      });

    tweetFetchPromises.push(promise);
  }

  $q.all(tweetFetchPromises).then(function() {    
    console.log('I\'m executed after all promises resolved');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add some custom and simple approach. Could be helpful.
Just adding some counters:

```
populate_tweets = function(callback){
     var counter = tweet_ids.length;
     var testCallback = function () {
       if(--counter < 1){
         callback();
       }
     };
     for(var t=0; t<tweet_ids.length; t++){
        $http.get('/echo/json/')
            .then(function(data){
                tweets_array.push(data);
                    testCallback();
            }, function(err){
                 testCallback();
               console.log(err)
            });
     }
   // This will be logged first because the Async calls are not completed yet
   console.log(tweets_array );          
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fedxgibson/3pdno898/